# Couldn't give the different Time Interval to the specific Slide in Twitter BootStrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am in a trouble that I want to give **

-

> a different time interval to a specific slide

**. The reason of doing this is that I added a **.swf file** to the slide which I want to let it play. I am not able to find any way after a huge searches in all sites. Because there are only two events are there slide and slid. Using them I couldn't be able to do this.Please help me out. If is there any other way of doing the same Please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: same problem here... see that whether it helps you or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650472/bootstrap-carousel-interval-on-each-slide-working-after-2-slides-not-on-first-an